# Background process that is run on file is still running after the file is deleted

Tags: android, service, process, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

So i have a process in Android that is run like this:

```
   process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandString);
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             Log.d("ShutDownHook Called");
             process.destroy();
        }
   }));
```

Where the command string contains a file path and some other arguments.
That process is a CPU heavy process and can take last as long as a few hours (Movie transcoding). The file is an ffmpeg static file. The problem is in some cases the process stays in the background even though i killed the app. That situation is on one of my phones when i kill the app with the task manager. That being said, the onDestroy() method is not called, nor is the onTerminate() from the application class, nor the shutdown hook from above.

Also i have created a background service with a notification, so when exit the app the service should stay in the background. Even with this kind of control, when i kill the application with the task manager, the service is restarted and i lose all the references to my ffmpeg class, Async task, process etc, and i cannot stop the process because i have null pointers.
Anyway i can ensure that the service will not be tampered with the app kill, so i can kill the process with the notification bar from my service?

```
ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d("HelperActivity", "onServiceDisconnected");
        mIsBound = false;
        mServer = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d("HelperActivity", "onServiceConnected");
        mIsBound = true;
        NotificationService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (NotificationService.LocalBinder)service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
        //mServer.test();
    }
};
//This is the onCreate of the application class
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,
            NotificationService.class);

    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    Log.d("onCreate", "Called");
    singleton = this;

}
```

I have been using http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/ for the ffmpeg support. Of course added new features but the basic concept of running a ffmpeg command is the same.

One other strange thing is, when i start the app i delete the previous file, and still the process is running in the background, cause my transcoding performances are halved. The file is copied from assets to the internal storage every time the app is started.

```
  File ffmpegFile = new File(FileUtils.getFFmpeg(context));
  if (ffmpegFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("File exists!");
        ffmpegFile.delete();
  }
```

The file is deleted i checked, but my CPU is still used a lot.
Sorry for any mistakes during the post, it is my first one.